# How to use " sign as a string?

Tags: r, string

My problem is that I would like to put a " sign in front of a string and it doesn't work.

So I have a string, let's say: hello
And I would like to get a string: "hello

How is this possible in R?

Thank you for your help in advance!

I have tried the as.string() function but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes or a backslash before the sign.

```r
'"hello'
#> [1] "\"hello"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work, because I'm trying to put this sing in front of and right after a date, and I'm using the date later in a an API request. And the request doesn't work because of the \ sign.

Comment: @Lili please provide a better example of your problem than the one you provided in your question.